# Query Multiple Fields-array Firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have some checkboxes in my android app. I want to do a firestore query on the basis of checkboxes checked by the user. I've managed to add the names of all the checked fields in an array.
So if my app has 10 checkboxes with names - item 1,item 2......item 10 ,and if user checks boxes 3,4 and 10. I get an array:

```
testArray=[item 3,item 4,item 10]
```

Now I want to query this array against the boolean value- true. My database is also containing fields namely  item 1,item 2......item 10 with different boolean values .

I tried this:

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
             .collection("Users")
             .whereEqualTo(testArray.toString(),true)
             .get()
             .addOnSuccessListener(
   new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
   @Override
   public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
     List<DocumentSnapshot> 
     snapshotList=queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments();
     for(DocumentSnapshot snapshot:snapshotList){
                  Log.d("TAG", "onSuccess: "+snapshot.getData());
                }
           }
     }).addOnFailureListener(
   new OnFailureListener() {
   @Override
   public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

   }});
```

I got the error:

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Use FieldPath.of() for field names containing '~*/[]'.
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.Preconditions.checkArgument(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.3:117)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.FieldPath.fromDotSeparatedPath(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.3:83)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.Query.whereEqualTo(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.4.3:94)
        at com.example.XX.todayQuestionFragment$1.onClick(todayQuestionFragment.java:134)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7201)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7170)
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:806)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27582)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7710)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:516)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
```

Now i tried using FieldPath.of() as recommended by the IDE. i.e I replaced

```
testArray.toString()
```

with:

```
FieldPath.of(testArray)
```

Using this, I was not getting any error but I was also not getting my data. My logcat was empty in the debug section.

How can I make this query? Please keep in mind that I don't know the contents or the size of the array. It depends on the user input. The problem is not getting the array from checkbox,it is making query where the fields are members of an array.
Any insights would be very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a single boolean field and you want to test if that field is equal to one of the value in your array, you're looking for the `whereIn` function:

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
         .collection("Users")
         .whereIn("nameOfField", testArray);
```

---

If you hav an array field with booleans and you want to test if any of those booleans match any of the values in your local array, you're looking for `whereArrayContainsAny`:

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
         .collection("Users")
         .whereArrayContainsAny("theArrayField", testArray);
```

---

If you have multiple fields in your document that you want to test, it essentially becomes a `WHERE field1 = true OR field2 = true`.

This is a type of query that Firestore doesn't support.against, so you'll have to perform a separate query for each field.

---

**Update** It turns out your use-case is different, and you want to build an `AND` query, which Firestore *does* support.

Every time your call `where...` it returns a `Query` object. So you can loop over your fields, and create a new `Query` for each additional checkbox.

Something like:

```
// Start with the full list of all users
Query query = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Users")

// Add a condition for every value in our array
for (int i=0; i < testArray.length; i++) {
  String field = testArray[i];
  query = query.whereEqualTo(field, true);
}

// Execute the query
query.get().addOnSuccessListener(...
```

Comment: My local Array is CONTAINING the "nameOfField"s. Using my example again: I want all documents where item 3= true & item 4=true & item 10=true . In my code I'm already having the array [item3,item4,item10] .The members of my array correspond to the name of the fields in my documents. I want to use  `where`  but I don't know the names of the fields since they are in my array. Is there any way where I can loop through all the members of my array for my query?

Comment: Perfect. Thanks! So if a person clicks on 5 check boxes,there will be 5 queries,right? I mean I will be billed according I guess. And also if I want a simple `query.whereEqualTo("name","George")` along with this, i.e a one time query. Should I add it in the for loop itself? Thanks again

Comment: It's 5 query objects, but only is actually sent to the server: the final one with five `whereEqualTo` clauses.